# Do you get a Eigen value without the respective Eigenvector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was solving some problems on diagonalization of matrixes, and I came across a particular question which seemed a bit odd.
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-8 & -6 & 2\\
-6 & 7 & -4\\
2 & -4 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

I found the eigen values to be $\lambda_1 = -10.13$, $\lambda_2 = 11.44$, and $\lambda_3 = 0.69$
All the values are rounded off to 2 decimal places.

The problem comes when I try to find the eigenvectors, I tried to substitute the value of lambda and find the null space, But I get a zero vector. I know that for a eigen value there should be a eigen vector, Then why am I not getting it.
Have I done something wrong? Or is my approach Wrong?

Comment: @Moo Thank you for pointing out, The matrix I entered was wrong, I apologize. I have edited the matrix, Please do look into it.

Comment: You cannot have an eigenvalue without a corresponding eigenvector. Eigenvalues are defined to be the scalars $\lambda$ for which there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: Of course, if you are *rounding*, then you aren't actually checking the eigenvalues, you are checking some other scalars...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I agree. But while I am trying to solve the above problem I cannot seem to get the eigen Vector of eigen value -10.13. I get a zero vector for the null space of the obtained matrix. Could you please post an answer to get the eigen vector for -10.13

Comment: As a rule, if you round an eigenvalue, you have to solve for an “almost-eigenvector,” which is much harder to do.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok so if we round off the values there is another method through which we solve for eigen vectors. Thank you for that.

Comment: When you subtract the rounded eigenvalue from the diagonal you don't zero out one of the diagonal values. Instead, you make is smaller so your matrix is still invertible. That's why you get zero as the only solution to the null space.

Comment: @jdsouza Was that a question or an assertion?

Comment: In the current solution that I have rewritten (the previous one was wrong, sorry about that) I use the standard polynomial root approximation method that is used in numerical methods and the like for vectors. I think this fully answers your first question about the diagonalizable nature of the matrix and partially gives an answer to avoiding trivial solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rough and ready way to find an (approximate) eigenvector, given an (approximate) simple eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $n \times n$ matrix $A$, is the following.  Let $B$ be the
top left $n-1 \times n-1$ block of $A-\lambda$, and $C$ the top $n-1$ entries of the
last column of $A-\lambda$.
$\lambda$ being a simple eigenvalue, $A-\lambda I$ should have rank $n-1$. Usually, $B$ will have rank $n-1$:
if not, you'll have to adapt this method to use another row and/or column instead of the last one.  Then the approximate eigenvector is $\pmatrix{u\cr 1\cr}$, where $B u = -C$.

In the given example, with $\lambda = −10.130887$, we have $B = \pmatrix{2.130887 & -6\cr -6 & 17.130887}$, $C = \pmatrix{2\cr -4\cr}$, so
$u = \pmatrix{-20.361293 \cr -6.897936}$.  And indeed $\pmatrix{-20.361293 \cr -6.897936 \cr 1\cr}$ is a good approximation to the eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

In this approach we will use numerical approximation by Mathematica:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}-8&-6&2\\-6&7&-4\\2&-4&2\end{bmatrix}\in M_{3}({\bf R})$ then the matrix is ${\bf R}$-symmetric matrix, then all the eigenvalues must be reals and also the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalues is the same of geometric multiplicity and therefore $A$ is ${\bf R}-$diagonalizable.

The characteristic polynomial is given by
$$f(t)=-t^{3}+2t^{2}+115t-80$$
the polynomial can be written as
$$f\left(t-\frac{2}{3}\right)=-\left(t-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+\frac{349}{3}\left(t-\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{74}{27}$$
Solving that we can control a better numerical approximation of the roots (eigenvalues) to $f$, we get
$$t_{1}\approx-10.130886904486$$
$$t_{2}\approx 0.690226155068582$$
$$t_{3}\approx 11.4406607494200$$
This allows to make a better approximation avoiding the jump to zero as you pointed. Then each eigenspace is obtained by,
$$E_{t_{k}}={\bf ker}(A-tI_{3})$$

If you want you can do this by hand, I do not recommend it. Using the computational power of Mathematica, we can find a pretty good approximation for the eigenvectors

$$t_{1}\longrightarrow  v_{1}\approx \begin{bmatrix}-20.36\\-6.90\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$t_{2}\longrightarrow v_{2}\approx \begin{bmatrix}-0.13\\0.54\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$t_{3}\longrightarrow v_{3}\approx \begin{bmatrix}0.65\\-1.78\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

The idea is that the more decimal places you add in your approximation for the roots, the better approximation you get to perform the row reduction. In fact it is possible to calculate or control the error in this approximation, but this is all part of the computational theory related to numerical methods. Due to the nature of the roots it's hard to get better than this. However, using polynomial theory we can find a closed form of the roots. Thanks to all fellow users for your corrections in the comments, they are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a symmetric matrix.  Symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Comment: The zeros of this polynomial match (to 2 decimals) the roots given by the OP.

Comment: Since $f(0)=-80 \lt 0$, $f(1)=36>0$, and $f(20)=-4980\lt 0$, the polynomial has at least two real roots, and hence has three real roots. So it splits completely over $\mathbb{R}$. Don't know where you get that it doesn't.

Comment: @DougM Real symmetric matrix are diagonalizables. However that's not necessarily is true over ${\bf C}$ just take $\begin{bmatrix} 1&i\\i&-1\end{bmatrix}$ with is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes @ThomasAndrews you're right. I saw the polynomial and did not stop to think a little more. Thank you very much, I will delete this post.

Comment: I have re-written my entire previous post. I don't know if the formal thing was to do that or write another answer and delete this one, there's the edit history anyway. Thanks for the corrections they are important to me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be tried is the "power iteration"  method.  They require the matrix be diagonalizable.  I am not sure what you do with a non-symmetric matrix.  Start with a nonzero vector $v.$   At each step,   find  $v_{i+1}  = \frac{Av_i}{|A v_i|}.$  Convergence may be slow, but eventually it settles and $v_{n+1}$  is numerically identical to $v_n,$   so that $Av_n$  is a multiple of $v_n$ which is thus an eigenvector. Below is the end of 125 steps, beginning with (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

```
  -0.304230773143   0.830909487335  -0.465868072022
  -0.304470778919   0.830828180736   -0.46585628565
  -0.304258250982   0.830900181732   -0.46586672419
  -0.304446448626   0.830836425831  -0.465857481888
  -0.304279797232   0.830892884361  -0.465865667027
  -0.304427370169   0.830842890742  -0.465858419689
  -0.304296692363   0.830887161911  -0.465864837897
  -0.304412409931   0.830847959891  -0.465859154923
  -0.304309940417   0.830882674533   -0.46586418764
  -0.304400678981    0.83085193466  -0.465859731366
  -0.304320328682   0.830879155693  -0.465863677684
   -0.30439148026   0.830855051339  -0.465860183327
  -0.304328474494   0.830876396366   -0.46586327777
  -0.304384267169   0.830857495192  -0.465860537696
  -0.304334861923   0.830874232628  -0.465862964157
  -0.304378611096   0.830859411478  -0.465860815552
  -0.304339870541   0.830872535932  -0.465862718226
  -0.304374175944    0.83086091409  -0.465861033417
  -0.304343797984   0.830871205471  -0.465862525373
  -0.304370698166   0.830862092333  -0.465861204247
   -0.30434687764   0.830870162196  -0.465862374144
  -0.304367971104    0.83086301623  -0.465861338197
  -0.304349292514   0.830869344117  -0.465862255557
  -0.304365832709   0.830863740689  -0.465861443229
  -0.304351186108   0.830868702627  -0.465862162565
  -0.304364155909   0.830864308762  -0.465861525587
  -0.304352670947   0.830868199607  -0.465862089646
  -0.304362841066   0.830864754208  -0.465861590166

   -3.48200897706    9.50567668652   -5.32976946946
  Ratios  

    11.4403222314    11.4407027598    11.4406716114
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Here are the last lines up to 275 steps

```
  -0.304358064764   0.830866372321  -0.465861824749
  -0.304358064764   0.830866372321  -0.465861824749
  -0.304358064764   0.830866372321  -0.465861824749
  -0.304358064764   0.830866372321  -0.465861824749
  -0.304358064764   0.830866372321  -0.465861824749

   -3.48205736531    9.50566029383   -5.32976709306
  Ratios  

    11.4406607494    11.4406607494    11.4406607494
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

next morning: it occurred to me that I could save  the unit eigenvector found above.  Then start over, at each step    project  $Av$   so that it becomes perpendicular to the first eigenvector, then normalize.  This requires the matrix to be symmetric, so that eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. It worked well:

```
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796
   0.9461022184874291   0.3205176193068897 -0.04646555592057795
  -0.9461022184874294  -0.3205176193068897  0.04646555592057796

   9.584854575581929   3.247127752094036  -0.470737291985566

  Ratios:  

   -10.1308869045   -10.1308869045   -10.1308869045
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$